# Manually set Assembly package name, but Install plugin ignores them

Tags: java, maven

I am having a problem with some functionality I need configured.
Here is a part of my POM, where I configured a project to be assembled into two different files: FirstNameProject-VERSION-bin.zip and SecondNameProject-VERSION-bin.zip.
The idea is that I **had** to maintain those names set, even if the original artefact is common.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.project.my</groupId>
<artifactId>MyGenericProject</artifactId>
<name>Generic Project</name>

<version>2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
<build>
     <plugins>
        ....
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>first</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>FirstNameProject-${project.version}-bin</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/resources_first.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>second</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>FirstNameProject-${project.version}-bin</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/resources_second.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>                   
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is working properly and in the `mvn package` logs I can see:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:single (first) @ MyGenericProject ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/resources_first.xml
[INFO] Building zip: C:\MyPath\MyProject_trunk\target\FirstNameProject-2                                                                   .0.2-bin.zip
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:single (second) @ MyGenericProject ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/resources_second.xml
[INFO] Building zip: C:\MyPath\MyProject_trunk\target\SecondNameProject-2.0                                                                   .2-bin.zip
```

The problem is that, at during **install**, it just reverts to the generic name and install the the rightly named file as the Generic one!

[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ MyGenericProject ---
[INFO] Installing C:\MyPath\MyProject_trunk\target\MyGenericProject-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:.m2\repository\com\project\my\MyGenericProject\2.0.2-SNAPSHOT\MyGenericProject-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\MyPath\MyProject_trunk\pom.xml to C:.m2\repository\com\project\my\MyGenericProject\2.0.2-SNAPSHOT\MyGenericProject-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\MyPath\MyProject_trunk\target\FirstNameProject-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip to C:.m2\repository\com\project\my\MyGenericProject\2.0.2-SNAPSHOT\MyGenericProject-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.zip

I am imagining that this is because the install plugin has no visibility on exactly how the assembly plugin was configured so I ask you: how can I configure the install plugin so that I will end up with **FirstNameProject-VERSION-bin.zip** and **SecondNameProject-VERSION-bin.zip** installed in my repository??

I hope I was clear enough,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Maven is "attaching" the assembly artifact to the project under the default name.  The first option is to scour the assembly plugin configuration to see if there's a way to control this.  Looking through it myself, I don't see a way to do this.  I would have thought it would have used your final name configuration, but if it doesn't, it doesn't.

The workaround I can offer, and I would hope someone can offer something more standard, is to [configure the assembly to NOT attach itself](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#attach).

Next, take the file it creates, the one with the name you want, and use the [build-helper plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) to attach the file under the precise coordinates that you want.